# Configure postfix to catch all email for domain

Tags: postfix

I have a Java app that acts as mailing list and needs to process all incoming mail for subdomain.example.com.

How do I set up postfix to catch all incoming mail?

I've seen a few other posts for this question, but I also want to know should/can the catch all address be a real unix account or a virtual mail box?

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seems pretty straightforward](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/), basically you just edit the virtual file so that all mail for sudomain.domain.com just goes to the email account you select.  Have you tried that approach?

It doesn't matter at all if you use a real or virtual account, that's purely up to you.  If you already have a real user account on the box, use it.  If it's too much hassle to create a real user account, use a virtual account.  Virtual accounts are more secure because they can't be used for other things like ssh'ing into the system.